# What is the AS3 script to place my externally loaded .swf to a lower layer. Right now it goes to the very top of my stage covering my navigation

Tags: actionscript-3

What is the AS3 script to place my externally loaded .swf to a lower layer?  Right now it loads to the very top of my stage covering my navigation. Thank you for your time.

Comment: addChild(loader) -> addChildAt(loader, 0)

Comment: Thank you. I will try that.

Comment: So do I change the zero in the (loader, 0) to a -1 to make the .swf load to a lower layer?

Comment: Disregard, it worked when I changed the 0 to 2.  Your awesome! Thank you!!!

Comment: No, 0 is the lowers layer of any display container. Also, these actions are not linked in any way. You can load SWF with Loader class without putting it to any layer, also you can put a display object to a certain layer of display container without loading it.

Comment: Another way is to use an empty container that you place on your top left corner and add the loaded content there: myContainer.addChild(loader); This way you can place the container on a specific level you need and don't need to adjust the layer when you will get more objects on the stage.